# CSS Positioning Absolute (4 Diamonds close together)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive

Hello Stackoverflow users!

I need your assistance once again.

I am trying to put 4 diamonds together in the center of a page to act as navigation on a landing page. the 4 diamonds should make a diamond of them self and I really cannot think how to do this.

I have tried doing position absolute but then its screwed responsive.

I have bootstrap on this website so maybe there is a solution with columns? I have tried everything please help.

```css
.diamond-top {
  position: absolute;
  top: 25%;
  left: 39%;
}
.diamond-left {
  position: absolute;
  left: 30%;
  top: 38%;
}
.diamond-right {
  position: absolute;
  left: 48%;
  top: 38%;
}
.diamond-bottom {
  position: absolute;
  top: 51%;
  left: 39%;
}
.diamond-container {
  width: 212px;
  height: 212px;
  padding: 30px;
}
.diamond-container:hover .tile-link {
  -webkit-animation: rotateYaxis 5s linear infinite;
}
.tile-link {
  font-size: 20px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  line-height: 150px;
  -webkit-transition: 1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: 1s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: 1s ease-in-out;
  transition: 1s ease-in-out;
  transform-origin: center;
}
.tile-link:hover {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.tile-link:hover:before {
  background: yellow;
}
.tile-link:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background: white;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 5px yellow;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  transition: 1s ease-in-out;
}
@-webkit-keyframes rotateYaxis {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 720deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="diamond-top">
  <div class="diamond-container">
    <a href="#" class="yellow tile-link">Link 1</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="diamond-left">
  <div class="diamond-container">
    <a href="#" class="yellow tile-link">Link 2</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="diamond-bottom">
  <div class="diamond-container">
    <a href="#" class="yellow tile-link">Link 3</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="diamond-right">
  <div class="diamond-container">
    <a href="#" class="yellow tile-link">Link 4</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: 4 Diamonds Creating 1 Diamond Navigation.]

Comment: Here is a link that will show you how to create diamond shapes: https://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/ this is your first challenge getting this correct.

Comment: How do you mean, 4 diamonds should make a diamond..? Do they have to be aligned or inside of eachother or.. ?

Comment: Hello, Please refresh I have added an image to show you what I mean. Also the individual diamonds them selves are fine but thank you Andrew.

Comment: Would it be easier to make a container for your diamonds? You could make a `div` with `position:absolute` and center that while inside the `div` you can use `position:absolute` or `relative` for the diamonds. The coordinates of the individual diamons can then be given in absolute values relative to the container's top-left.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please ad a parent div with relative position. Something like the code below and set the position for the diamonds related to this div.

```
.wrap{
  position:relative;
  width:300px;
  height:300px;
}

<div class="wrap">
    ...
</div>
```

My solution is here, but I added the values with inspect element, you can update with something more specific I think

```css
   .wrap{
  position:relative;
  width:300px;
  height:300px;
}
.diamond-top {
  position: absolute;
  top: 25%;
  left: 39%;
}
.diamond-left {
position: absolute;
left: 13px;
top: 60%;
}
.diamond-right {
position: absolute;
left: 75%;
top: 60%;
}
.diamond-bottom {
position: absolute;
top: 95%;
left: 39%;
}
.diamond-container {
  width: 212px;
  height: 212px;
  padding: 30px;
}
.diamond-container:hover .tile-link {
  -webkit-animation: rotateYaxis 5s linear infinite;
}
.tile-link {
  font-size: 20px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  line-height: 150px;
  -webkit-transition: 1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: 1s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: 1s ease-in-out;
  transition: 1s ease-in-out;
  transform-origin: center;
}
.tile-link:hover {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.tile-link:hover:before {
  background: yellow;
}
.tile-link:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background: white;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 5px yellow;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  transition: 1s ease-in-out;
}
@-webkit-keyframes rotateYaxis {
  0% {
-webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 0deg);
  }
  100% {
-webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 720deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
<div class="diamond-top">
  <div class="diamond-container">
    <a href="#" class="yellow tile-link">Link 1</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="diamond-left">
  <div class="diamond-container">
    <a href="#" class="yellow tile-link">Link 2</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="diamond-bottom">
  <div class="diamond-container">
    <a href="#" class="yellow tile-link">Link 3</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="diamond-right">
  <div class="diamond-container">
    <a href="#" class="yellow tile-link">Link 4</a>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I implemented here, but the values are a quick implement. https://jsfiddle.net/MadalinaTn/5nb076h5/5/

Comment: Thank you perfect!

Answer (score 3):

Wrap the diamond in a wrapper and position it relative to the wrapper.

```css
.diamond-wrapper{
    position: absolute;
    width: 272px;
    height: 272px;
    padding: 30px;
    left: 150px;
    top: 150px;
    margin: auto;
}

.diamond-top {
  position: absolute;
  top: -25%;
}
.diamond-left {
  position: absolute;
  left: -25%;
}
.diamond-right {
  position: absolute;
  right: -25%;
}
.diamond-bottom {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -25%;
}
.diamond-container {
  width: 212px;
  height: 212px;
  padding: 30px;
}
.diamond-container:hover .tile-link {
  -webkit-animation: rotateYaxis 5s linear infinite;
}
.tile-link {
  font-size: 20px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  line-height: 150px;
  -webkit-transition: 1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: 1s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: 1s ease-in-out;
  transition: 1s ease-in-out;
  transform-origin: center;
}
.tile-link:hover {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.tile-link:hover:before {
  background: yellow;
}
.tile-link:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background: white;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 5px yellow;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  transition: 1s ease-in-out;
}
@-webkit-keyframes rotateYaxis {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 720deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="diamond-wrapper">
<div class="diamond-top">
  <div class="diamond-container">
    <a href="#" class="yellow tile-link">Link 1</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="diamond-left">
  <div class="diamond-container">
    <a href="#" class="yellow tile-link">Link 2</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="diamond-bottom">
  <div class="diamond-container">
    <a href="#" class="yellow tile-link">Link 3</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="diamond-right">
  <div class="diamond-container">
    <a href="#" class="yellow tile-link">Link 4</a>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you perfect!

Answer (score 1):

Hey i have a suggestion for this solution. Give some gentle hover effect too.

Like this

```
<div class="DiamondContainer">
      <div class="dmd dmd1">
          <div>
            <a href="#" class="yellow tile-link">dmd</a>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="dmd dmd2">
          <div>
            <a href="#" class="yellow tile-link">dmd</a>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="dmd dmd3">
          <div>
            <a href="#" class="yellow tile-link">dmd</a>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="dmd dmd4">
          <div>
            <a href="#" class="yellow tile-link">dmd</a>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The CSS is

```
.DiamondContainer{
  width:230px;
  transform:rotateZ(45deg);
  margin:200px;
  background-color:#000;
}
.dmd{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  float:left;
    border: 2px solid #ffc65f;
    background-color: #fffaf1;
    transition: all 0.5s ease  
}
.dmd a{
  display:block;
  transform:rotateZ(-45deg);
  line-height:100px;
  text-align:center;
  color:#000;
  text-decoration:none;
}
.dmd1:hover{
  position: relative;
    left: -22px;
    top: -24px;
    background: #ffc65f;
    border: 2px solid #fffaf1;
    color: #fff;    
}
.dmd2:hover{
    position: relative;
    left: 22px;
    top: -22px;
    background: #ffc65f;
    border: 2px solid #fffaf1;
    color: #fff; 
}
.dmd3:hover{
    position: relative;
    left: -22px;
    top: 22px;
    background: #ffc65f;
    border: 2px solid #fffaf1;
    color: #fff; 
}
.dmd4:hover{
    position: relative;
    left: 22px;
    top: 22px;
    background: #ffc65f;
    border: 2px solid #fffaf1;
    color: #fff; 
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/befLws89/

```css
.DiamondContainer{
  width:230px;
  transform:rotateZ(45deg);
  margin:200px;
  background-color:#000;
}
.dmd{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  float:left;
    border: 2px solid #ffc65f;
    background-color: #fffaf1;
    transition: all 0.5s ease  
}
.dmd a{
  display:block;
  transform:rotateZ(-45deg);
  line-height:100px;
  text-align:center;
  color:#000;
  text-decoration:none;
}
.dmd1:hover{
  position: relative;
    left: -22px;
    top: -24px;
    background: #ffc65f;
    border: 2px solid #fffaf1;
    color: #fff;    
}
.dmd2:hover{
    position: relative;
    left: 22px;
    top: -22px;
    background: #ffc65f;
    border: 2px solid #fffaf1;
    color: #fff; 
}
.dmd3:hover{
    position: relative;
    left: -22px;
    top: 22px;
    background: #ffc65f;
    border: 2px solid #fffaf1;
    color: #fff; 
}
.dmd4:hover{
    position: relative;
    left: 22px;
    top: 22px;
    background: #ffc65f;
    border: 2px solid #fffaf1;
    color: #fff; 
}
```

```html
<div class="DiamondContainer">
      <div class="dmd dmd1">
          <div>
            <a href="#" class="yellow tile-link">dmd</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="dmd dmd2">
          <div>
            <a href="#" class="yellow tile-link">dmd</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="dmd dmd3">
          <div>
            <a href="#" class="yellow tile-link">dmd</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="dmd dmd4">
          <div>
            <a href="#" class="yellow tile-link">dmd</a>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I think your this solution will be fine with the UI.